# Using gdal_translate: how to extract a raster layer into a new tif and keep the original's metadata

Tags: gdal, metadata, gdal-translate

I am trying to extract each raster layer from a geoTiff into a separate tiff. I can do this quite easily by doing

```
gdal_translate -b 1 input.tif output.tif
```

However I need to preserve the metadata from the original geoTiff into the separated raster tiff. I have been playing around with the API on this link (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) however have been unsuccessful

Any idea on how to do this?